# Jquery to Python / Django Query Dict

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

I'm `POST`ing an array using JQuery as such:

```
var fees = [];
fees.push({
                        "fee":someFee0,
                        "deadline": someDeadline0,
                        "category": someCategory0})
                });

fees.push({
                        "fee":someFee1,
                        "deadline": someDeadline1,
                        "category": someCategory1})
                });
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: /save/,
                    data: {fees:fees},
                    success: ...
```

When I get `POST` data to my Django app, it shows up as such:

```
<QueryDict: {u'fees[1][deadline]': [u'31'], u'fees[0][category]': [u'43'], u'fees[1][fee]': [u'fdsa'], u'fees[1][category]': [u'44'], u'fees[0][fee]': [u'fdas'], u'fees[0][deadline]': [u'31']}>
```

How can I access it such that I use the data as meaningful objects.

```
# fees[0], fees[1] turned int dicts of this format
{"category": 43, "fee": "fdas", "deadline": 31}
```

Alternatively, if I use `JSON.stringify(fees)` in my JQuery, my `POST` data turns up strange:

```
<QueryDict: {u'[{"fee":"fdsa","deadline":"31","category":"43"},{"fee":"fdsa","deadline":"31","category":"44"}]': [u'']}>
```

However I can access the relevant data I desire using:

```
x = request.POST    
for values in x.lists():
        data = json.loads(values[0])
print data[0]['fee'], data[1]['deadline']
```

I feel like this is all duct tape and band-aids though.
What am I doing wrong / What is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `JSON.stringify` version then get the data in Python via `json.loads(request.body)`.

Comment: Awesome! It does. But why so?

Comment: Because `request.POST` is for form-encoded data, but you're posting JSON directly. `request.body` is the raw post.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `json.dumps(my_query_dict)` , I think.